# National Flags and their Venn Diagrams

Tags: knowledge, visual, geography, flags

***Which cities are X, Y and Z?***
[image]

---

*The colours in the Venn Diagrams in no particular order are **White, Red, Light Blue, Dark Blue and Black***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

X

> Manchester

Y

> Milan

Z

> Berlin

Because

> Each venn diagram represents the colors (outfits) of two football teams from the same city. From left to right; 1. **Manchester** United - **Manchester** City, from England. 2. AC **Milan** - Inter **Milan**, from Italy. 3. Hertha BSC (B stands for **Berlin**) - FC Union **Berlin**, from Germany.